# HTML input CSS background color not applied

Tags: html, css

I have an odd CSS behaviour on `input[type=number]` elements that is causing the set `background-color` to not be applied. The `color` style is being applied to the input's text properly and Chrome's dev tools shows the background-color as being active on the element but the actual input value is rendered with a different background-color (light-gray and not black #000 as shown).

Has anyone experienced such behavior? Are there other CSS properties that can be causing this?

Any suggestions or solutions to this are much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: try adding `background:#000;` and see if it's overrided or not

Comment: Thanks @th31 but that had no effect.

Comment: check then if you're selecting the right element. i can't see the  class `.hmi` in your html code

Comment: @th31 I verified the appropriate element(s) are selected and the styles pane in my screenshot shows this. The `.hmi` class is set on a `md-content` element that is 3 levels above the input elements. I don't see how this background style is not being rendered.

Comment: Maybe you should post your css too, since you have many classes applied to the input element. That may help show what other class are effecting the input. Also, have you tried using a different format for the background color, like RGBA? It is worth a shot :) I hope you can get it working. Good luck!

Comment: Can you show us your CSS stylesheet where you have written the code for background-color?

Comment: Is the opacity set to less than 1?

Comment: Please do post your CSS and HTML otherwise, we can only assume what the problem might be!

Comment: No one will be able to understand the issue properly. Please post minimal code

Comment: Check if you don't have another rule written down below your stylesheet file(s) that is overriding this behavior you set for this class. If there is a different rule later on the same file or in a different file that loads after this one affecting the same element, that could cause this.

Answer (score 6):

As others have commented, we can only guess what is happening from the limited information we have in this screenshot, but I will name a few possible explanations that you may check in your code.

And about the background-color not being applied; actually it is applied as I can see: the input is 50px width according to css, and I see in the inspector it's 50px width so the black around the value is the background-color as you set it. Only the value has grey around it. And: as setting background-color !important does override the background-color itself, it does NOT override ALL background properties (if for instance somewhere else a background IMAGE has been declared, that will not be overridden)

So, a list of possible explanations:

- Background image could be set.
- The grey background could be your browser's prefilled background that appears when an input value is autocompleted from stored memory. Chrome for instance sets a background that is usually yellow (but may be grey in your case). You can try to find out if this is the case with:

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active  {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset !important;
}
```

- The input may somewhere have `all: unset` which overrides other css declarations
- A browser extension may be messing with your html/css. Open the page in an anonymous tab (which usually has extensions disabled).
- There may be some css ::pseudo selector set that changes the color, scroll down in your element inspector to see. They are usually at the bottom. such as input::valid

Answer (score 2):

I think you are facing this issue because autofill css property 
which is led my default through css. If you want to override it use this code:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: red !important;
}
```

you can change background color as you want by replacing "white" in first line
you can change text color as you want by replacing "red"

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Angular` and style changes in `HTML` or `CSS` is not visible, apply the following approach:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    ... 
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try `alert` class for the background color of the **input** tag.They look really good for the **input** tags.Even I had this issue once and using `alert` class worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to be more specific with the selector. Try an id to set the colour. Once I faced the same problem. Solved it by being more specific.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all of the above.

1. In your console switch **Styles** tab to **Computed**, and you will see all properties that can have an influence on your `input`.
2. This strange gray color is `#e8e8e8` or `rgb(232,232,232)`. try to look for it in your **css** files.
3. There is a plenty of classes in you `input`. Try to remove them one by one in console and see whats happens.

And you can although try to null `text-shadow`, of course. Using text shadow i could made the same result as you.

```
input {
    text-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of classes for that particular element, it is possible that one of them is causing it to behave abnormally, there's no way for me to tell that without seeing the CSS file, I would advise you to try assigning the input element an ID to see what happens as it has a higher order in the rendering of the page. That's all I can think about for now.